# Cython complains that generated pxd-defined C code is gil-requiring

Tags: cython, gil

I have some code that is ripe for simple parallelizing. However, it uses a C library. How do I define functions in pxd files as nogil? They are pure C so I do not see the problem...

This is the error message I get:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                    it = NULL
                    output[nfound] = indexes[i]
                    nfound += 1

            i += 1
            cn.free_interval_iterator(it_alloc)
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ncls/src/ncls.pyx:545:37: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil
```

This is an example of the definitions in my pxd file:

```
int free_interval_iterator(IntervalIterator *it)
IntervalIterator *reset_interval_iterator(IntervalIterator *it)
int find_intervals(IntervalIterator *it0,
                   int start,
                   int end,
                   IntervalMap im[],
                   int n,
                   SublistHeader subheader[],
                   int nlists,
                   IntervalMap buf[],
                   int nbuf,
                   int *p_nreturn,
                   IntervalIterator **it_return)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is after the function definition.

```
IntervalIterator *interval_iterator_alloc() nogil
```